# Dynamically adding scripts makes conflict and not works properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I was dynamically adding the scripts and link tags to the page from another page through ajax call response value, some time its not adding to page, some times its not working, occurs conflict with each other while loading.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    siteResponse();
    $(window).error(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
function siteResponse() {
    var protocol = "http://IP/";
    var server = "Site/";
    var accessPage = "Home.aspx";
    var url = protocol + server + accessPage;
    var res = "";
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        options.async = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            res = result;
            var str = res; 
            var scrpt = /<(?:SCRIPT|script \b[^>]*)>([\s\S]*?)<\/(?:SCRIPT|script)>/gm;
            var lnk = /<link([\s\S]*?)\b[^>]*\/>/g; 
            while (res3 = lnk.exec(str)) {
                $("#footerSection").append(res3[0]);
            }
            while (res2 = scrpt.exec(res)) {
                $("#footerSection").append(res2[0]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

links added properly to the page but scripts not working properly, sometime its conflicting with each other, some times its not loading to the page

Comment: From sometimes you mean it works occasionally right?

Comment: No, i have two sections in page which referring this scripts and links, any one of the section will work, other will not work, say eg: header will work but footer will not work, if footer works well then header will not work.